# Java beginner question - add multiple items to screen

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jcomponent

I'm a complete beginner trying to learn Java as my first language. When I'm adding TYPE and Skills to the window, only the one added last (in this case, skills) appears. How do I get both to appear?

Thanks,
Ravin

```
public class Funclass extends JFrame{
    FlowLayout layout = new FlowLayout();
    String[] Skillz = {"Analytical", "Numerical", "Leadership", 
          "Communication", "Organisation", "Interpersonal"};
    public Funclass(){
        super("Title Bar");
        JTextField Company = new JTextField("Company Name");
        JComboBox TYPE = new JComboBox();
        JList Skills = new JList(Skillz);
        TYPE.addItem("Choose which type of firm");
        TYPE.addItem("Consultancy");
        TYPE.addItem("Tech");
        Skills.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
        add(TYPE);
        add(Skills);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to add

```
setLayout(layout);
```

in the constructor.

Comment: Awesome cheers! Embarrassing omission but hey you gotta learn somehow!

Comment: If that's embarrassing, prepare to be embarrassed a lot as you learn Java. :)

Answer (score 1):

You forget to set the layout manager that you have delcared `FlowLayout layout = new FlowLayout();`, so you just need to add `this.setLayout(layout);` inside your constructor.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a direct answer to your question but if you are just beginning to learn Java, I think you should probably not start with trying to build user interfaces with Swing ("Swing" is the part of Java you are using here to build a GUI, and it is fairly complicated).  You are really jumping in at the deep-end.

One minor nit-pick about your code.  Java convention for naming variables and methods is to use "camel-case" and begin with a lower-case character, "somethingLikeThis".  So your variable names should all be lower-case since they are all just single-words.  ie. "skills", "type", "company".

I highly recommend the book "The Java Programming Language" by Ken Arnold for Java beginners.